# Missing multiprocessing module when freezing Python code

Tags: python, distutils, cx-freeze

I'm using cx_Freeze to freeze my Python code so I can distribute it as executable on Windows systems. It works fine but it's missing a few modules. I use some open-source libraries in my project e.g. BeautifulSoup and Periscope. They use some libraries for backward compatibility which i don't need to include as Python 2.6 has them. The problem is the third import — **multiprocessing._multiprocessing**. Can anyone tell me what I need to install in order to fix this? The mutiprocessing module seems to come bundled with Python so what's causing this error?

```
Missing modules:
? cjkcodecs.aliases imported from BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup
? iconv_codec imported from BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup
? multiprocessing._multiprocessing imported from multiprocessing.forking
? xdg.BaseDirectory imported from periscope.periscope
```

Any help?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct version of cx_Freeze? I see this on their website: 

"NOTE: Binary packages must be compatible with the Python installation on your system or you will get errors in your frozen executables about missing builtin modules"

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.2 and I downloaded cx_Freeze module for Python 2.6. I don't think it's a version issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a similar issue on Google App Engine. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1504)

I fixed this my putting a _multiprocessing.py file into the multiprocessing module's folder. This file contained the code:

> import multiprocessing

This works but it isn't a robust answer.

Comment: Most freezers, also pick up `if False: import multiprocessing`. I don't know about py 2.6, but in python 3 cx-freeze it works